# typeahead empty result but ajax call is working

Tags: jquery, typeahead

I've used [jquery typeahead](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/) in my project.

My first typeahead will display brand car, result will not change often.

I tried two different way and get same result, typeahead is empty.

I see my ajax call return data

> [{"brandId":1,"brand":"Acura"},{"brandId":2,"brand":"Alfa
>   Romeo"},{"brandId":3,"brand":"AMC"},{"brandId":4,"brand":"Aston
>   Martin"},{"brandId":5,"brand":"Audi"},{"brandId":6,"brand":"Avanti"}]

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="brand" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Marque</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="typeahead-container">
            <div class="typeahead-field">
                <span class="typeahead-query">
                    <input id="brand" name="brand" class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Entrer la marque" autocomplete="off">
               </span>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>

    $('#brand').typeahead({
     minLength: 3,
     source: {
      url: {
       type: 'GET',
       url: '/brands'
      }
     }
   });
```

i tried also this way

```
getAllBrand().done(brandTypeahead);

function getAllBrand(){
  return $.ajax({
    url:'http://localhost:8080/brands',
    type:'GET'
  });
}

function brandTypeahead(data){
 $('#brand').typeahead({
        minLength: 3,
        source: data
 });
}
```

edit

```
$('#brand').typeahead({
  minLength: 3,
  source: {
    brand:{
      url: {
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/brands'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

same result

if i add display:"brand", that work

Comment: Doesn't seem to match the config examples in their documentation. `url` is always a level deeper under `source`. Also, it says the response header of the AJAX call **must** be `application/json`; have you checked that?

Comment: ajax result is application/json...